# Протопотоки. Как использовать в обычном C99

Tags: c, многопоточность, библиотеки

Требуется решить проблему многозадачности.

Т.к. времени в обрез и писать что-то на asm особо не хочется...

Короче, прочитал, что псевдомногопоточность можно реализовать протопотоками.

Но примеры там не то что для чайников, а для прожженых самоваров)

Никак не пойму как сделать следующее:

Имеется структура:

```
struct SimpleProcess{   // Одиночный процесс 

        unsigned char Priority;         // Приоритет
        unsigned char SecurityLevel;    // Уровень безопасности
        unsigned char Status;           // Статус процесса
        void(*Function)();              // Функция 

    };
```

Так вот, нужно *Function* выполнить в отдельном протопотоке. Как это сделать?
Т.е. есть функции

```
void PrintHello(){
  while (true) printf("BEEP!\n");
}

void PrintBuy(){
      while (true) printf("OOOP!\n");
    }
```

Есть маин:

```
int main(){
  struct SimpleProcess SP[2];
  ...
  SP[1].Function = PrintHello;
  ...
  SP[2].Function = PrintBuy;
  ...
  // Запуск протопотоков
}
```

Сорри за примеры, пытался написать простые, чтоб разобраться проще было.

Так вот, как запихнуть первые 2е функции в протопотоки для одновременного выполнения?

И что там пишут про локальные переменные?

Возможно не смог самостоятельно разобраться из-за гугл транслейта )

Comment: P.S. Т.к. пишу под нестандартную архитектуру - pthread не завести

Comment: Первый раз услышал про эти "протопотоки". Поэтому, может и не прав. Но: "про локальные переменные" - там пишут что не сохраняются. Надо всё хранить в статиках.  На мой взгляд, достаточно понятно описано тут: http://bsvi.ru/protopotoki-protothreads/

Comment: С таким подходом лучше Zephyr начать использовать, не уверен, правда, что там сейчас с многопоточностью.

Comment: @0andriy я свою ОС пишу

Comment: Использование библиотек, типа ПП, указанной выше, это уже не своя ОС. Тем не менее, удачи!

Comment: @0andriy why???

Comment: https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "pt.h"

#define true    1

struct SimpleProcess
{
    unsigned char Priority;
    unsigned char SecurityLevel;
    unsigned char Status;
    struct pt Context; // Переменная для хранения контекста протопотока
    char (*Function)(struct pt *Context); // Для протопотока необходим указатель на 
                                          // контекст
};



PT_THREAD(PrintHello(struct pt *Context)) // Объявление протопотока
{
    PT_BEGIN(Context);

    while (true)
    {
        printf("BEEP!\n");

        // Передача управления в main. 
        // При следующем вызове этого протопотока выполнение продолжится после 
        // макроса PT_YIELD.
        PT_YIELD(Context);
    }

    PT_END(Context);
}


PT_THREAD(PrintBuy(struct pt *Context)) // Объявление протопотока
{
    PT_BEGIN(Context);

    while (true)
    {
        printf("OOOP!\n");

        // Передача управления в main. 
        // При следующем вызове этого протопотока выполнение продолжится после 
        // макроса PT_YIELD.
        PT_YIELD(Context);
    }

    PT_END(Context);
}



int main(void)
{
    struct SimpleProcess SP[2];

    SP[0].Function = PrintHello;
    SP[1].Function = PrintBuy;

    // Инициализация контекстов
    PT_INIT(&SP[0].Context);
    PT_INIT(&SP[1].Context);

    // В бесконечном цикле вызываем протопотоки
    while (true)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            SP[i].Function(&SP[i].Context);
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

По поводу локальных переменных ничего особенного нет.
Нужно помнить, что после передачи управления с помощъю
макросов PT_... локальные переменные, расположенные в стеке
теряются. Если необходимо, чтобы локальные переменные
сохраняли свои значения между вызовами протопотока
их необходимо объявлять с использованием ключевого слова
static или использовать глобальные переменные.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]